# Android: Connecting to the server

Tags: java, android, server, httpconnection

I'm running a simple local server and I just want to watch in terminal if my app is succesfully connected to the server.

Installation and build is succesful, but nothing (by nothing I mean no connection, of course there aren't any data) happens. The **server** is surely **running**, the **port** is set to **8080**, my **phone** is **connected** to the internet (tried both wifi and data) I'm working with `Android Studio`, and I added these permissions to my manifest in:

> AndroidManifest.xml

```
...
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
...
```

> ActivityMain.java

```
package tlacitko.button;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URL;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void sendMessage(View view) {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        try{
                            URL url = new URL("http://147.32.186.51:8080");
                            InputStream is = url.openStream();
                            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new
                                    InputStreamReader(is));
                            String s = "";
                        }catch(MalformedURLException ex){

                        }catch(IOException e){

                        }

                    }
                });
            }
        }).start();

    }

}
```

Comment: Can you print the stacktrace?

Comment: Please send us the code where you call sendMessage().

Comment: It will obviously throw Networkonmainthreadexception... This new thread doesn't make sense as whole body is just post some runnable to run back on ui thread.

Comment: @BenjaminLucidarme you mean the xml part? There's only click button.

Comment: @Selvin I'm new to Java, I wouldn't use it, if it weren't absolutely necessary. So should I remove the `runOnUiThread` ? And leave its content in the `new Thread` ?

Comment: Firstly, both the device and terminal must be connected on the same network. Second, try checking your server side program to verify, whether the program is listening on the same port.